# How to use call_with_depth_limit/3

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, iterative-deepening

I'm trying to use [`call_with_depth_limit/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=call_with_depth_limit/3) in SWI-Prolog to implement iterative deepening and either I don't understand how it works or it's misbehaving. I have an example where the following happens:

```
?- call_with_depth_limit(mygoal, 29, Result).
Result = 29 ;
Result = 25 ;
Result = 27 ;
Result = 27 ;
false.
```

```
?- call_with_depth_limit(mygoal, 26, Result).
Result = depth_limit_exceeded ;
false.
```

According to the documentation it should succeed if the goal can be proved with Limit max recursion or less. In the first call with limit 30 we see results where the Result is 25, therefore I would expect that calling it with a limit of 26 it would succeed.
I'm using constraint handling rules in the module, in case there can be some interaction there that makes it misbehave.

**EDIT:** After playing with Isabelle's answer I think I understand how it behaves:

- It runs a depth first search like usual but if it gets to Limit+1 depth it acts as if it failed.
- Failed branches count towards the Result.
- Every time it backtracks after a successful answer, it resets Result to the current depth of the stack.

See this example:

```
loop :- loop.

succeed(0).
succeed(N) :- N > 0, N1 is N - 1, succeed(N1).

fail(N) :- N > 0, N1 is N - 1, fail(N1).
```

```
?- call_with_depth_limit(succeed(0), 1000, Result).
Result = 1 ;
false.

?- call_with_depth_limit(fail(50);succeed(0), 1000, Result).
Result = 53 ;
false.

% It tries loop until Limit+1 and therefore this is the Result
?- call_with_depth_limit(loop;succeed(0), 1000, Result).
Result = 1001 ;
false.

% In the second result it has to unroll the stack from 100 before trying the next, so Result is 100.
?- call_with_depth_limit(loop;succeed(100);succeed(0), 1000, Result).
Result = 1001 ;
Result = 103 ;
false.

?- call_with_depth_limit(loop;succeed(0);succeed(0), 1000, Result).
Result = 1001 ;
Result = 3 ;
false.

% If it gets to the end, and it has reached Limit+1 since the last successful result it returns depth_limit_exceeded.
?- call_with_depth_limit(loop;succeed(100);succeed(0);loop, 1000, Result).
Result = 1001 ;
Result = 103 ;
Result = depth_limit_exceeded.
```

Comment: Isn't it just that for the first successful result you need a depth of 29, which is evidently excessive, and then it blows? Then the next result for which you need a depth of 25 will never be attempted.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer  looks like that's an answer. :)

Comment: I tested thsi and pasted some code at [`call_with_depth_limit/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=call_with_depth_limit/3) in the comment section. Works as expected, everything is going extremely well.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not convinced that SWI-Prolog even implements its own specification for `call_with_depth_limit/3`. At least I read:

> If Goal can be proven without recursion deeper than Limit levels, call_with_depth_limit/3 succeeds, binding Result to the deepest recursion level used during the proof. Otherwise, Result is unified with depth_limit_exceeded if the limit was exceeded during the proof...

as implying that `Result` will never be greater than `Limit`. But with this program:

```
succeed_with_depth(3) :-
    succeed(3).
succeed_with_depth(1) :-
    succeed(1).

succeed(0).
succeed(N) :-
    N > 0,
    N1 is N - 1,
    succeed(N1).
```

I observe (SWI-Prolog 7.6.4):

```
?- call_with_depth_limit(succeed_with_depth(N), 5, Result).
N = 3,
Result = 5 ;
N = 1,
Result = 6 ;
false.
```

Proving the *shallower* goal results in a *deeper* recursion. A recursion that exceeds the limit but still succeeds.

Personally, reading the documentation I would expect to get the same depth for proving `succeed_with_depth(1)` on backtracking as when calling it directly:

```
?- call_with_depth_limit(succeed_with_depth(1), 5, Result).
Result = 3 ;
false.
```

Or maybe add 1 depth for backtracking at the outermost level of `succeed_with_depth`? That should still give `Result = 4` and not `6`.

**Edit:** As pointed out by rajashekar in the comments, adding a cut in the first clause of `succeed/1` changes the unexpected behavior the the expected one. I see this as further indication that SWI-Prolog's behavior is broken: The only difference is cutting away a choice that on backtracking will immediately fail. There is no actual deeper recursion in any succeeding computation.

**Edit 2**: To illustrate that the semantics I am imagining for this is simple, and that it can *actually* be used to implement iterative deepening, here is a small meta-interpreter that is just strong enough to execute my program from above:

```
interpret_with_depth_limit(Goal, Limit, Result) :-
    interpret_with_depth_limit(Goal, 0, Limit, Result).

interpret_with_depth_limit(_Goal, Current, Limit, depth_limit_exceeded) :-
    Current >= Limit,
    !.
interpret_with_depth_limit(Builtin, N, _Limit, N) :-
    builtin(Builtin),
    !,
    call(Builtin).
interpret_with_depth_limit((A, B), N, Limit, Result) :-
    !,
    interpret_with_depth_limit(A, N, Limit, ResultA),
    integer(ResultA),
    interpret_with_depth_limit(B, N, Limit, ResultB),
    integer(ResultB),
    Result is max(ResultA, ResultB).
interpret_with_depth_limit(Goal, N, Limit, Result) :-
    N1 is N + 1,
    N1 < Limit,
    clause(Goal, Body),
    interpret_with_depth_limit(Body, N1, Limit, Result).

builtin(true).
builtin(_ > _).
builtin(_ is _).
```

This doesn't retain depth information across backtracking, so behavior on backtracking is the same as when calling more specific instances of the goal:

```
?- interpret_with_depth_limit(succeed_with_depth(N), 6, Result).
N = 3,
Result = 5 ;
N = 1,
Result = 3 ;
false.

?- interpret_with_depth_limit(succeed_with_depth(3), 6, Result).
Result = 5 ;
false.

?- interpret_with_depth_limit(succeed_with_depth(1), 6, Result).
Result = 3 ;
false.
```

Iterative deepening, finding each answer exactly once and in the proper order (i.e., shallowest proofs first), is then:

```
call_succeedingdepth(Goal, Depth) :-
    between(1, infinite, Limit),
    Depth is Limit - 1,
    interpret_with_depth_limit(Goal, Limit, Depth).
```

Test:

```
?- call_succeedingdepth(succeed_with_depth(N), Depth).
N = 1,
Depth = 3 ;
N = 3,
Depth = 5 ;
% nontermination
```

I don't think anything can be done about the nontermination; you would usually use this on goals that have an infinite number of answers.

Comment: yes, that quote is very confusing and even possibly self-contradictory. it could be re-worded as "if the recursion depth did not exceed the Limit levels while proving Goal, call_with_depth_limit/3 succeeds, binding Result to the deepest recursion level used during the proof.". then it would be in agreement with the Q's observations. whether this is indeed what it does or not, I have no idea. :)

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie: introducing a cut after `N > 0` is giving what you want. Backtracking somehow is adding to depth limit.

Comment: @rajashekar No, adding a cut in the last clause of a predicate, after only determinate goals, does not change anything. Did you try this? I did, the results are the same as in my answer.

Comment: That has the same behavior with and without the cut, as far as I can tell. **But** it is running a newer version of SWI-Prolog, and its behavior is different from my version. This might be the relevant information, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Without the cut, I still get `X=1, Result = 6` in SWI-Prolog 8.2.2

Comment: Even in swish with version 8.3.15, I am getting different results with and without cut.

Comment: I just realized that you *also* added a cut in the first clause, which further muddles the issue. This one *does* change the behavior in my experiments, the one after `N > 0` does not. I'll experiment more.

Comment: Yes, the cut in the first clause is affecting the depth not the one after `N > 0` in the second.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Indeed iterative deepening is easy to implement. What I want is that it stops trying with higher depths if all branches fail before the current depth. And also I want to avoid a metainterpreter approach.

Also agree that call_with_depth_limit seems to be broken.

Answer (score 5):

I've tried to understand how `call_with_depth_limit/3` works by using this program:

```
%           a        <- 1st call
%         /   \
%        b     g     <- 2nd call
%       /
%      c             <- 3rd call
%     / \
%    g   d           <- 4th call
%        |
%        e           <- 5th call

arc(a, b).
arc(a, g).
arc(b, c).
arc(c, g).
arc(c, d).
arc(d, e).

path(X, X, [X]).
path(X, Z, [X|R]) :- arc(X, Y), path(Y, Z, R).
```

Results obtained:

```
?- call_with_depth_limit(path(a,g,P), 4, D).
P = [a, b, c, g],
D = 4 ;
P = [a, g],
D = 5 ;
false.
```

It seems that the answer:

- `P = [a, b, c, g], D = 4` means 4 calls to obtain the first solution.
- `P = [a, g], D = 5` means 5 calls to obtain the second solution (notice that, before obtain this second solution, the failure path `[a,b,c,d,e]` must be explored and the 5th call causes a failure  - this fact justifies the answer `D = 5`).

Another query:

```
?- call_with_depth_limit(path(a,g,P), 3, D).
P = [a, g],
D = 4 ;
false.
```

We can see that the search backtracks after 4 calls (`D = 4`), but the fourth call needed to obtain the solution `[a,b,c,g]` causes a failure (because `depth_limit` is 3) and does not produce a result.

**[EDIT] Another scenario:**  In this new scenario, a cut was added in the first clause of the predicate `path/3` to avoid the extension of a path which is already a solution (otherwise, the search will try one more step downward in this same path and will fail with depth 5 before finding the second solution).

```
%           a        <- 1st call
%         /   \
%        b     g     <- 2nd call
%       /
%      c             <- 3rd call
%     /
%    g               <- 4th call
%
%                    <- 5th call

arc(a, b).
arc(a, g).
arc(b, c).
arc(c, g).

path(X, X, [X]) :- !.
path(X, Z, [X|R]) :- arc(X, Y), path(Y, Z, R).
```

In this new scenario, we have:

```
?- call_with_depth_limit(path(a,g,P), 4, D).
P = [a, b, c, g],
D = 4 ;
P = [a, g],
D = 2.
```

We observe that:

- In this second scenario, the deepest recursion level reached to find the second solution is 2.
- However, in the first scenario, the deepest recursion level to find the second solution is 5 because, before finding the second solution, the search must try to extend path `[a,b,c,g]` and also explore the path `[a,b,c,d,e]` (hence, the deepest recursion level used during the proof of solution `[a,g]`is 5).

It is important to notice that, as stated in SWI-Prolog documentation, the `Result` is bound to *the deepest recursion level used during  the proof* of a **particular** solution, **not** to *the level in which this solution is found*.

> `call_with_depth_limit(:Goal, +Limit, -Result)`
> If   Goal   can   be   proven   without   recursion   deeper   than   Limit  levels,
> call_with_depth_limit/3 succeeds, binding Result to the deepest recursion level used
> during  the proof.  Otherwise, Result  is unified  with depth_limit_exceeded  if the
> limit was exceeded during the proof,  or the  entire predicate  fails if  Goal fails
> without exceeding Limit.

**Iterative deepening depth-first search**

Find a shallowest solution for `Goal`, without exceeding `Limit`:

```
ids(Goal, Limit) :-
    between(1, Limit, Depth),
    call_with_depth_limit(Goal, Depth, Result),
    Result \= depth_limit_exceeded,
    !.
```

Here are some examples (same answers for both scenarios):

```
?- ids(path(a,g,P), inf).
P = [a, g].

?- ids(path(a,g,P), 10).
P = [a, g].

?- ids(path(a,g,P), 2).
P = [a, g].

?- ids(path(a,g,P), 1).
false.
```

Comment: That kind of makes sense in this example, but then I don't get why would I get in my example first 29 and then 25. In order to get to the 25 result it has to first explore the 29 anyway, right?

Comment: @Joan Please, see **EDIT: Another scenario** in my answer. I think that will clarify your doubt.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't it just that for the first successful result you need a depth of 29, which is evidently excessive, and then it blows? Then the next result for which you need a depth of 25 will never be attempted.

Comment: Is there another way to get the what the OP requires? i.e., abandon the path when the depth limit is exceeded and search other paths.

Comment: @rajashekar Would standard iterative deepening whereby you fail on a too-deep attempt and backtrack "in-proof" (so to say) for another attempt help? It _would_ find the later, shallower proof tree.

Comment: One could perform successive `call_with_depth_limit/3` with shallow values (e.g. 3) when going down the proof tree, so that the sum of of the limits is less than some maximum (e.g. 29), and consider `depth_limit_exceeded` as an invitation to try another proof branch (i.e. a just local failure). I would have to try to program this out to make it clear in my head.--

Comment: Yes that would help, if limit is exceeded then fail and backtrack. I read somewhere that in some prologs we can adjust search strategies, So after some depth we can try other paths and if they all fail may go deeper(mix depth and breadth).

Answer (score 0):

According to [the SWI documentation](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=call_with_depth_limit/3),

> The depth limit is guarded by the internal machinery. This may differ from the depth computed based on a theoretical model. [...] As a result, call_with_depth_limit/3 may still loop infinitely on programs that should theoretically finish in finite time.

So its "depth" is different from from the depth computed based on a theoretical model.